# Asynctask, BroadcastReceiver and Service

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager, android-things

Using the alarm manager im trying to call an asynctask. First i do all the configurationof the alarm, when the alarm goes off it calls the broadcast receiver followed by a Service and finally the AsyncTask. However i have an error saying the Service can not be created: Zero no arguments. I belive the problem is on the manifest, maybe im creating the service wrong...

**Main activity:**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    WifiManager wifiManager;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); //Initialize wifi

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); //Create alarm
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, YourAlarmReceiver.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);



    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()==false)  //Check if wifi is on
    {
        Log.d("ERROR", "WIFI OFF");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("WiFI","Wifi ON");

        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),90000, pendingIntent);

        Log.e("ALRM","ALARM CREATED");
    }

    //new SendRequest().execute();
}
```

**Service, BroadcastReceiver and Asynctask**

```
public class ServiceAux extends Service{
    public ServiceAux(){
        super();
    }
    public void onCreate(){
        new SendRequest().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
public static class YourAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("SERVICE","SERVICE CREATED");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceAux.class));
    }
}

public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { ... } //Send information to a server
```

**My manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />


    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".HomeActivity$YourAlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"></receiver>
    <service android:name=".HomeActivity$ServiceAux"></service>
</application>
```

Comment: `".HomeActivity$ServiceAux"` - The `$` indicates that `ServiceAux` is a nested class in `HomeActivity`. Is that where it actually is? If so, then it must be `public static`. Or, just pull it out to its own class file, since you don't really gain anything from having it nested in the `Activity`. Also, you don't need the constructor in `ServiceAux`.

Comment: Yes ServiceAux is inside the home acitvity. It doesnt need to be there?

Comment: Nope. In fact, I'd say that's it's rather uncommon to have nested `Service` classes. `YourAlarmReceiver` doesn't need to be nested, either. Just make sure you update the `name`s in the manifest, if you pull them out to their own files.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will give it a try!

Comment: Ok i created a class file for ServiceAux and YourAlarmReceiver. However the service file give me an error: expected class or package. When i try this:{public class ServiceAux extends Service {
    
    public void onCreate(){
        new HomeActivity.SendRequest().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
}

Comment: It looks like you have extra braces - `{}` - around the whole class. The `Service` class should be structured just like any other class. Look at your `Activity` class to see how it is.

Comment: Thanks! Solved, working thank you!